# How to use UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a project whose `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, and in my project only the view controller loading a full screen `UIWebView`. I need to change its orientation.

I have finished fixing the issue, but there's some trouble: When a user is in the view controller with the web view in the *landscape orientation* then clicks the back button, the previous view controller is also in landscape orientation. I want it to be in portrait, however. Any ideas on how to do this?

If you can read Chinese, I found [this page](http://www.cocoachina.com/ask/questions/show/121091/%E5%AF%BC%E8%88%AA%E6%8E%A7%E5%88%B6%E5%99%A8%E4%B8%BA%E6%A0%B9%E6%8E%A7%E5%88%B6%E5%99%A8%E7%9A%84%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AE%E4%B8%AD%E6%A8%AA%E5%B1%8F%E8%BF%94%E5%9B%9E%E5%90%8E%E5%BC%BA%E5%88%B6%E7%AB%96%E5%B1%8F%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E5%81%9A), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

for whatever viewcontroller you require to stay in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

I have try many solution, but the correct answer with working solution is:

ios 8 and 9, no need to edit info.plist.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
 return NO;
 }   



- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait |  UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
 }
```

[possible orientation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation?language=objc)

UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown

The orientation of the device cannot be determined.

UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait

The device is in portrait mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the bottom.

UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

The device is in portrait mode but upside down, with the device held upright and the home button at the top.

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side.